# Unable to convert a espanol date to a unix timestamp; it returns Nan

Tags: javascript, localization, timezone, momentjs

The following works for normal dates but not for Localized dates. Can someone please help

The below returns Nan

moment("04 de feb. de 2021").endOf("day").unix()
NaN

The below works

moment("04 Feb 2021").endOf("day").unix()
1612463399

Comment: Does moment support multiple languages?

Comment: `moment("04 de feb. de 2021")` is an invalid date.

Comment: Does my answer make sense?

Comment: Yes..i could resolve the issue with the hint..i figured out the reason for getting invalid date and solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly parse dates in a non-ISO format, a format must be provided alongside the date string.

```js
console.clear();

console.log(
  moment(
    "04 de feb. de 2021",
    "DD [de] MMM[. de ]YYYY"
  ).toISOString()
);

console.log(
  moment(
    "04 de feb. de 2021",
    "DD [de] MMM[. de ]YYYY"
  )
  .endOf("day").unix()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

For more information, please [read the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).